# Modem > Managed Switch > Router

Tags: switch

I am looking to connect my modem to a smart or managed switch then to my router. The reason why is because my line coming in is downstairs, and I only have one line from there running upstairs which is where I want to put my router. So I figured I would connect the modem downstairs to the smart or managed switch then plugged in to the upstairs ethernet port which would be my router. Is this possible to do with a managed or smart switch and how would I go about setting that up?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So isn't `managed switch` just the same thing as router? It always got me confused...

Comment: Normally a router would be connected directly to a modem. Why put a switch in the middle? Is there a switch upstairs also? Is that the reason? Look into `vlans` and `vlan tagging`... not something I'm overly familiar with but I believe that's what you need.

Comment: @Anubioz No, not the same thing. "Router" requires layer 3 functionality, which only some managed switches possess. Many managed switches operate exclusively at layer 2.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you will want two managed* switches.

When you want to carry multiple seperate logical networks over the same physical connection you use 802.1q VLANS. Lets say we use VLAN 10 for the internal network and VLAN 20 for the modem to router connection. Our configuration might look like.

Downstairs switch

- Link to upstairs: VLAN 10 native, VLAN 20 tagged
- Link to modem: VLAN 20 native
- Remaining ports: VLAN 10 native

Upstairs switch:

- Link to downstairs: VLAN 10 native, VLAN 20 tagged
- Link to WAN side of router: VLAN 20 native
- Link to LAN side of router: VLAN 10 native
- Remaining ports: VLAN 10 native

* "smart" switches are basically low end managed switches. Some seem ok, others have serious design flaws such as no ability to contol which VLAN the management interface is on. Read the manual carefully (when I looked at TP-link the "smart" series seemed ok while the "websmart/easysmart" series seemed like crap),

Comment: Thanks for coming along... I couldn't explain this because I've never done it but I really thought it might work. :) +1 for you.

Comment: Why does the WAN side of the modem need to plug into the switch? Wouldn't it go out to the internet downstairs, since that's where he placed it where his line is?

Comment: Umm, the phrase "WAN side of the modem" doesn't appear anywhere in my post.

Comment: Woops.  `Link to WAN side of router: VLAN 20 native`. I misread. Sorry.